# How can I add a route in a custom blueprint?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am creating a custom blueprint in EmberJS, and am curious how I can programmatically add a route to the main router.js from my blueprint.  I have the actual routes built in the /app/routes/ directory, now I just need to add them to the main router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ember-router-generator`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-router-generator). Have a look at the code of the "route blueprint" [at github](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/blueprints/route/index.js#L118).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the right thing.  Are there docs anywhere?

Comment: I had searched about this at February 2016. I found no docs. [The code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/blueprints/route/index.js#L118) is clear enough.

Comment: But I've changed my router.js update code after March or April. Because I've created an instance-initializer to read my json files with route configurations and to submit configurations to the router. By this way, I had resolved issue of too much conflict in router.js. So I removed my initial code.